# How to select in jQuery elements by name array tag

Tags: jquery, arrays, select

This selection in jQuery:

```
$('[name=managers[]]')
```

throws

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=managers[]]
```

How do I escape those square brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `[]` is special characters, you can either wrapping your value inside double quotes:

```
$('[name="managers[]"]')
```

or escape the `[` and `]` with two backslashes

```
$('[name=managers\\[\\]]')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the `[]` in the name attribute which try to act as a new attribute selector. Try wrapping the value in `""`

```
$('[name="managers[]"]')
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uvVK4/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uvVK4/)